# Getting the "always trust" on web app in java 8

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, applet, signed-applet

Currently I have javafx apps embedded in a webpage for presentation, and for some run-time bugs, i need to use Java 8 jre.

And in Java 8, the option to "always trust from this publisher" no longer exist, and the pop up will always appear for unknown publisher. It is very annoying to have it pop-up every time I switch app.

I tried creating custom certificate and import to java in control panel, but it didnt work.

Is there any way I can disable the pop-up or the the "always trust" back?

Answer (score 1):

> ..in Java 8, the option to "always trust from this publisher" no longer exist, and the pop up will always appear for unknown publisher..

That's not a decision by MS, it is a decision by Oracle.

The fix is to digitally sign the applet using a certificate from a Certification Authority. A certificate that has a trusted key chain.

Comment: If I get a digitally sign from Certification Authority, I know it will replace the "unknown publisher" with the "authorized publisher", but will I see the pop-up every time I reload the app like refreshing the page?

Comment: *"will I see the pop-up every time I reload the app like refreshing the page"* Not if you tick 'always allow'.

Comment: so in Java 8, the "always allow" exist for authorized publisher but not the unknown publisher?

Comment: Again, Java 8 is *not relevant*.  It is the same security environment on Java 7.  Or on *any* OS running a recent Oracle JRE.